# Connecting to the new Bluez HDP plugin using DBUS from QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, dbus

I'm attempting to get readings from a device using the bluetooth Health Device Profile (specifically, an Nonin Onyx II 9560BT). Using this [guide](http://senzala.epx.com.br/2010/11/hdp-in-bluez.html), I've been able to do so using python over dbus. Now I'm trying to port it over to C++, and as I'm already using QT in the application, I'm using the QT DBus bindings.

So far I've gotten to the following short program based on [this API](http://git.kernel.org/?p=bluetooth/bluez.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/health-api.txt;hb=HEAD) to test it:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QStringList>
#include <QtDBus/QtDBus>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    if (!QDBusConnection::sessionBus().isConnected()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.\n"
                "To start it, run:\n"
                "\teval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`\n");
        return 1;
    }

    QDBusInterface iface("org.bluez","/org/bluez","org.bluez.HealthManager",QDBusConnection::systemBus(),0);

    QVariantMap map;
    map.insert("DataType",ushort(1004));//same result with simply 1004
    map.insert("Role","Sink");
    map.insert("Description","HDP Test Manager"); //Optional
    //map.insert("ChannelType","Reliable");//Optional, same result with or without
    //QList<QVariant> argumentList;
    //argumentList.append(map);

    QDBusPendingReply<> r = iface.call("CreateApplication",map);

    qDebug() << r.reply();
    qDebug() << r.error();
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the dict object taken by "CreateApplication" corresponds to an a{sv} which in QT corresponds to the QVariantMap.
However, I keep getting this error:

```
QDBusMessage(type=Error, service="", error name="org.bluez.Error.InvalidArguments", error message="Invalid arguments in method call", signature="", contents=([]) )
```

Question: What am I doing wrong?
Based on the guides at freedesktop.org, the qt docs and the mighty google, this is as far as I've gotten.

Thanks for any/all help!

/Keyz182

Answer (score 1):

It works now. It seems that the ushort(0x1004) was getting cast by the QVariant to an int, and thus being picked up as a uint32 by the bluez code, which is not what was expected.

To fix it I did the following (there may be another way, but this worked for me).

I added a Metatype declaration for ushort, then registered it. then, created a QVariant containing the value, and used the QVariants convert method to set the metatype as a ushort (or uint16 when exposed to dbus).

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QStringList>
#include <QtDBus/QtDBus>

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ushort); //Added this to declare ushort as a metatype

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    int ushorttype = qDBusRegisterMetaType<ushort>(); //Register the ushort metatype and get it's id

    if (!QDBusConnection::sessionBus().isConnected()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.\n"
                "To start it, run:\n"
                "\teval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`\n");
        return 1;
    }

    QDBusInterface iface("org.bluez","/org/bluez","org.bluez.HealthManager",QDBusConnection::systemBus(),0);

    QVariant dt(0x1004);
    dt.convert((QVariant::Type)ushorttype); //convert to the new type

    QVariantMap map;
    map.insert("DataType",dt);
    map.insert("Role","Sink");
    map.insert("Description","HDP Test Manager"); //Optional

    QDBusPendingReply<> r = iface.call("CreateApplication",map);

    qDebug() << r.isValid();
    qDebug() << r.reply();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, just curious how far you took this code.  I'm looking to do something similar.